# jquery $.each not giving all the information in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovam2r11/2/)

I want to put the names of all record in my array into a table my array isn't index correctly so i used `$.each` instead of iterating over the using `for loop`. My problem is I only get to show the last element but if i try to show a value that is existing to both the array it is showing correctly.
What am i missing in this code.
Any idea is appreciated

This is my javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    var names = name[i].Names;
    $.each(names, function (item, names) {
        tr = $('<tr class=""/>');
        //console.log(complainant[obj]);
        //var names = complainant[obj];
        //if(names.hasOwnProperty('fname')){
        console.log(names.suffix);
        var acronymc;
        var upper = names.mname.toUpperCase();
        if (upper) {
            var matches = upper.match(/\b(\w)/g);
            //var matches = upper.replace(/^(\S+)\s+(\S).*/, '$1 $2.');
            //acronym = upper.slice(0,1);
            var acronym1 = matches.join('');
            acronymc = acronym1.slice(-1);
        } else {
            acronymc = '';
        }
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<span id='fname'>" + names.fname + "</span>" + " " + "<span id='mname'>" + acronymc + "</span>" + " " + "<span id='lname'>" + names.lname + "</span>" + " " + "<span id='suffix'>" + names.suffix + "</span>" + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + '<span id="street">' + names.street + '</span>' + " " + '<span id="brgy">' + names.brgy + '</span>' + " " + '<span id="town">' + names.town + '</span>' + " " + '<span id="city">' + names.city + '</span>' + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + names.contactnum + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a href='#' class='editcomplainant'>Edit</a>" + "/" + "<a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a>" + "</td>");

        //}

    });
    $("#nameslist").append(tr);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `$('#nameslist').append(tr);` call inside the `$.each` block.

Here is a way of improving the creation of tds:

```
var html =
   "<td>" +
     "<span id='fname'/> " +
     "<span id='mname'/> " +
     "<span id='lname'/> " +
     "<span id='suffix'/>" +
   "</td>";

var td = $(html);

td.find('#fname').text(names.fname);
td.find('#mname').text(acronymc);
td.find('#lname').text(names.lname);
td.find('#suffix').text(names.suffix);

tr.apppend(td);
```

Why is this better (imho)?

- You will not create unintentional html tags by having `<` and `>` inside the variables.
- Appropriate escaping (auml codes) will be automatically generated
- It is easier to read

Comment: give me a few minutes to tick the answer